# Hibernate Lazy Loading doesn't work with forEach() in java 11

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, java-11

I don't know where one reports java bugs.  I can honestly say I've never seen one before.  BUT the lazy load of hibernate JPA and Java foreach doesn't work in Java 11.0.2.  I do not see it listed as fixed in 11.0.3 but didn't test.

It does work in Java 8.  So I suppose buyer beware!

Frameworks:
Spring Boot 2.1.1 (Spring 5.1.3)
Hibernate 5.3.7.Final

**BEGIN EDIT**
Partial Parent Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REST_ENDPOINT")
public class RestEndpoint extends AuditModel {
    private String  endpointName;
    private String  httpVerb;
    private String  httpTemplate;
    private String  serviceName;
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restEndpoint", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
public List<RestEndpointParam> params = new ArrayList<>();

public void addRestEndpointParam(RestEndpointParam param) {
    params.add(param);
    param.setRestEndpoint(this);
}

public void removeRestEndpointParam(RestEndpointParam param) {
    params.remove(param);
    param.setRestEndpoint(null);
}

public void setParams(List<RestEndpointParam> params) { this.params = params; }

public List<RestEndpointParam> paramsList() {
    return params;
}
```

**END EDIT**

The Child table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REST_ENDPOINT_PARAM")
public class RestEndpointParam {
...
private Long endpointId;
private RestEndpoint restEndpoint;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ENDPOINT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public RestEndpoint getRestEndpoint() { return restEndpoint; }
```

Now for the scary part.  With 2 items in the child table, The first foreach does not even print the log statement.

```
    // First set up the URI replacement variables    
    restEndpoint.paramsList().forEach(restEndpointParam -> {
        logger.warn("ENDPOINT 1st forEach access PARAM:{}", restEndpointParam.getType());
        if (restEndpointParam.getType().equals("URI")) {
            uriParams.put(restEndpointParam.getKey(), restEndpointParam.getValue());
    }});

// Now apply the Query parameters
    restEndpoint.paramsList().forEach(restEndpointParam -> {
        logger.warn("ENDPOINT 2nd foreach access PARAM:{}", restEndpointParam.getType());
        if (restEndpointParam.getType().equals("QUERY")) {
            builder.queryParam(restEndpointParam.getKey(), restEndpointParam.getValue());
    }});
```

The second forEach works as expected.  So it is the first reference that fails.  Also replacing the first access (forEach) with a conventional loop:

```
for (RestEndpointParam restEndpointParam : restEndpoint.paramsList())
```

The results are as expected.  So obviously there is an loading problem between hibernate and Java 11.

Comment: If the second `restEndpoint.paramsList().forEach` works but the first one does not, the logical assumption is that the problem lies in the first `forEach`. But it's hard to tell without a stacktrace and explanation of what "doesn't work' means...

Comment: Have you tried to set a break point in the forEach method of Iterable?

Comment: I did set breakpoints.  Actually that is why I added the log statement.  In the first case the lamba is not executed at all.  In IntelliJ I can see parmlist has 2 entries.  But my only explanation is that it evaluates as size()==0 - or more probably null.  Otherwise forEach should execute.

Comment: Please post the code or `paramsList()`. I'm guessing you are accessing `params` in there, which would explain why it is broken, because you are actually side stepping JPAs Lazy Loading.

Comment: @Jens Schauder I added the entire section showing how I map the child table.  I will admit I had some problems with this so it may not be "the right way".  But it does work in Java 8. The down side of "the internet remembers everything" is that stuff that hasn't worked in 7 years are the first 10 pages of google hits.  So  good; working; modern; code is very hard to find for stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this works with Java 8 or why the second `foreach` works.

But `paramsList()` is accessing the field `params` directly. Hibernate attaches lazy loading to getters but since there are no getters this doesn't work.

If your rename `paramsList()` to `getParams()` Hibernate should detect it as the getter and perform propper lazy loading.

Comment: TBH I don't see how JPA lazy loading is being side-stepped here. Hibernate initializes lazily-fetched lists with `PersistentList`s and the `PersistentList` itself is responsible for loading the data on first access. You only need to go through the getter for the inverse, optional side of a `@OneToOne`, not for multi-valued associations

Comment: It sounds like the solution I figured out for my other question is what is causing this.  But with my structure I cannot just change parmsList to getParams because then I get the error that Hibernate SessionFactory cannot determine the type for the List.  If you would be so kind as to review my previous issue it will probably be  illuminating (as well as humorous)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048028/spring-jpa-manytoone-doesnt-instantiate-children